# Solve $\sin{2x}-\cos{x}<0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following inequality:

$$\sin{2x}-\cos{x}<0$$
$$2\sin{x}\cos{x}-\cos{x}<0$$
$$\cos{x}(2\sin{x}-1)<0$$

The inequality is verified for

$$\cos{x}>0\space\vee2\sin{x}-1>0\rightarrow\sin{x}>\frac 1 2$$

$$0<\sin{x}<\frac 1 2$$

I found the following solutions (I've drawn a unit circle)

$$0<x<\frac \pi 6\space\vee\frac 5 6 \pi<x<\pi$$

My book suggests the following set of solutions:

$$0<x<\frac \pi 6\space\vee\frac \pi 2<x<\frac 5 6 \pi\space\vee\frac 3 2 \pi<x<2\pi$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The condition you imposed is wrong: the inequality is verified if and only if $$(\cos x<0\wedge 2\sin x-1>0)\vee (\cos x>0\wedge 2\sin x-1<0)$$

Comment: general solotion is $\frac{\pi}{2}(4k-1) < x < \frac{\pi}{6}(12k+1)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}(4k+1) < x < \frac{\pi}{6}(12k+5)$ for integer k.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone could tell me what's wrong with the grid I used to get to the conditions I imposed I would really appreciate it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/voIuq.png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The inequality $\cos{x}(2\sin{x}-1)<0 $ is solved when the two factor have opposite sign, so it reduce to two systems:

$$
\begin{cases}
\cos x>0\\
2\sin x-1 <0
\end{cases}
\quad \lor \quad
\begin{cases}
\cos x<0\\
2\sin x-1 >0
\end{cases}
$$

Can you do from this?

The figure illustrate the solution in the interval $0<x<2\pi$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emilio! Your solution is undeniably correct. Could you please tell me what's wrong with the sign grid I've drawn here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/voIuq.png?

Comment: Ho aggiunto una figura, va bene per chiarire?